# Связать рисование в виджете QCalendarWidget с нажатием кнопки QPushButton

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, qpushbutton, qcalendarwidget

У меня есть программа, которая после нажатия на дату в виджете календаре `QCalendarWidget` отмечает её красным кругом.

А как сделать так, чтобы дата отмечалась после клика на неё, а затем на `QPushButton`?

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QCalendarWidget, QMainWindow
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QColor
from PyQt5.QtCore import QRect, QDate, QPoint


class Calendar(QCalendarWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.events = []

    def paintCell(self, painter, rect, date):
        super().paintCell(painter, rect, date)
        if date in self.events:
            painter.setBrush(QColor(255, 0, 0))
            painter.drawEllipse(rect.topLeft() + QPoint(12, 7), 3, 3)


class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 500, 500)
        self.setWindowTitle('----')
        self.cal = Calendar(self)
        self.cal.move(100, 100)
        self.cal.clicked.connect(self.run)

    def draw(self, qp):
        qp.setBrush(QColor(255, 0, 0))
        qp.drawRect(0, 0, 30, 30)

    def run(self):
        date = self.cal.selectedDate()
        self.cal.events.append(date)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, не создавайте лишнюю работу другим участникам, вандализируя собственные посты. При размещении сообщения на сайте «Stack Overflow на русском» вы даёте SO, в соответствии с лицензией [CC BY-SA 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/deed.ru), неотзываемое право на распространение своего контента. В соответствии с политикой SO любые вандальные действия будут отменены. Если вы желаете узнать больше про удаление постов, пожалуйста, прочитайте ["Как работает удаление?"](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2293/223536).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как вариант:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, 
                            QCalendarWidget, QMainWindow, QVBoxLayout)
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QColor
from PyQt5.QtCore import QRect, QDate, QPoint


class Calendar(QCalendarWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.events = []

    def paintCell(self, painter, rect, date):
        super().paintCell(painter, rect, date)
        if date in self.events:
            painter.setBrush(QColor(255, 0, 0))
            painter.drawEllipse(rect.topLeft() + QPoint(12, 7), 3, 3)


class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
#        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 500, 500)
        self.setWindowTitle('Calendar')
        self.cal = Calendar(self)
#        self.cal.move(100, 100)
#        self.cal.clicked.connect(self.run)

        btn = QPushButton("Click me", self, clicked=self.run)      # +++ 

        self.vBox = QVBoxLayout(self)                              # +
        self.vBox.addWidget(self.cal)
        self.vBox.addWidget(btn)

#    def draw(self, qp):
#        qp.setBrush(QColor(255, 0, 0))
#        qp.drawRect(0, 0, 30, 30)

    def run(self):
        date = self.cal.selectedDate()
        self.cal.events.append(date)
        self.cal.setFocus()                                         # +++

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]